# Сommon file to use the slider

Tags: php, html, laravel, laravel-blade

I have a slider on my page that has fields `bg_image`, `short_description`, `person_image`, `person_name`, `person_position`

Here is the code

**blade.php**

```
<div class="section">
  <div class="section-wrapper section-padding">
    <div class="container">
      <h2 class="section-title testimonials-title">What value our Clients set upon our Partnership</h2>

      <div id="navWrapper" class="testimonials-nav">
        <div id="prevArrow" class="testimonials-nav__arrow">
          <img src="/img/arrow-left.svg" alt="arrow left icon">
        </div>
        <div id="navText" class="testimonials-nav__text"></div>
        <div id="nextArrow" class="testimonials-nav__arrow">
          <img src="/img/arrow-right.svg" alt="arrow right icon">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="testimonials-slider-wrapper">
      <div id="testimonialsSlider" class="testimonials-slider">
        <div id="testimonialsSliderRow" class="testimonials-slider-row">
          @foreach($testimonials as $testimonial)
          <div class="testimonial">

            <div class="testimonial-image d-none d-lg-block" style="background-image: url({{ $testimonial->bg_image }})"></div>
            <div class="testimonial-image d-lg-none" style="background-image: url({{ isset($testimonial->bg_image_mobile) ? $testimonial->bg_image_mobile : $testimonial->bg_image }})"></div>

            <div class="testimonial-text">{{ $testimonial->short_description }}</div>

            <div class="testimonial-person">
              <div class="testimonial-person__image">
                <img src="{{ $testimonial->person_image }}" alt="{{ $testimonial->image_alt }}" title="{{ $testimonial->image_title }}">
              </div>
              <div class="testimonial-person__name">{{ $testimonial->person_name }}</div>
              <div class="testimonial-person__position">{{ $testimonial->person_position }} - {{ $testimonial->person_location }}</div>
            </div>
          </div>
          @endforeach
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The `js` code is not needed in the prnice, but if I need to add, now in another question

I need to use the exact same slider on another page and the only thing that will be different is the fields in the slider, there will be `bg_image`, `title`, `date`, `views` and the title of the slider, which is now in the `testimonials-title` class

I want to create a separate blade.php file to use the same slider code for multiple pages

I create this file (I do not edit the names of the classes so as not to get confused)

```
<div class="section">
  <div class="section-wrapper section-padding">
    <div class="container">
      <h2 class="section-title testimonials-title">What value our Clients set upon our Partnership</h2>

      <div id="navWrapper" class="testimonials-nav">
        <div id="prevArrow" class="testimonials-nav__arrow">
          <img src="/img/arrow-left.svg" alt="arrow left icon">
        </div>
        <div id="navText" class="testimonials-nav__text"></div>
        <div id="nextArrow" class="testimonials-nav__arrow">
          <img src="/img/arrow-right.svg" alt="arrow right icon">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="testimonials-slider-wrapper">
      <div id="testimonialsSlider" class="testimonials-slider">
        <div id="testimonialsSliderRow" class="testimonials-slider-row">
          @foreach($testimonials as $testimonial)
          <div class="testimonial">

            <div class="testimonial-image d-none d-lg-block" style="background-image: url({{ $testimonial->bg_image }})"></div>
            <div class="testimonial-image d-lg-none" style="background-image: url({{ isset($testimonial->bg_image_mobile) ? $testimonial->bg_image_mobile : $testimonial->bg_image }})"></div>

            <div class="testimonial-text">{{ $testimonial->short_description }}</div>

            <div class="testimonial-person">
              <div class="testimonial-person__image">
                <img src="{{ $testimonial->person_image }}" alt="{{ $testimonial->image_alt }}" title="{{ $testimonial->image_title }}">
              </div>
              <div class="testimonial-person__name">{{ $testimonial->person_name }}</div>
              <div class="testimonial-person__position">{{ $testimonial->person_position }} - {{ $testimonial->person_location }}</div>
            </div>
          </div>
          @endforeach

          /*
          @foreach($article->article_recommendations as $article_recommend)
          <div class="article-recommend">

            <div class="article-recommend-image d-none d-lg-block" style="background-image: url({{ $article_recommend->image_list}})"></div>
            <div class="article-recommend-image d-lg-none" style="background-image: url({{ isset($article_recommend->image_list_mobile) ? $article_recommend->image_list_mobile: $article_recommend->image_list}})"></div>

            <div class="article-recommend-title">{{ $article_recommend->title }}</div>

            <div class="article-recommend-date">{{ date('d F Y', strtotime($article_recommend->published_at)) }}</div>

            <div class="article-recommend-views">{{ $article_recommend->getTotalViews() }} Views</div>
          </div>
          @endforeach
          */
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

In the same code, I put another `@foreach` for `$article_recommend`, what should I do now? It is like checking if there is a slider for the page where testimonials, if on the article page then another one. Or what is the best way to make one common slider?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will give you two ways of implementing this, one using include and one using view composers. Add the following script to `resources/views/slider.blade.php`:

### Slider.blade.php

```html
<div class="section">
    <div class="section-wrapper section-padding">
        <div class="container">
            <h2 class="section-title testimonials-title">What value our Clients set upon our Partnership</h2>

            <div id="navWrapper" class="testimonials-nav">
                <div id="prevArrow" class="testimonials-nav__arrow">
                    <img src="/img/arrow-left.svg" alt="arrow left icon">
                </div>
                <div id="navText" class="testimonials-nav__text"></div>
                <div id="nextArrow" class="testimonials-nav__arrow">
                    <img src="/img/arrow-right.svg" alt="arrow right icon">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="testimonials-slider-wrapper">
            <div id="testimonialsSlider" class="testimonials-slider">
                <div id="testimonialsSliderRow" class="testimonials-slider-row">
                    @foreach($testimonials as $testimonial)
                        <div class="testimonial">

                            <div class="testimonial-image d-none d-lg-block" style="background-image: url({{ $testimonial->bg_image }})"></div>
                            <div class="testimonial-image d-lg-none" style="background-image: url({{ isset($testimonial->bg_image_mobile) ? $testimonial->bg_image_mobile : $testimonial->bg_image }})"></div>

                            <div class="testimonial-text">{{ $testimonial->short_description }}</div>

                            <div class="testimonial-person">
                                <div class="testimonial-person__image">
                                    <img src="{{ $testimonial->person_image }}" alt="{{ $testimonial->image_alt }}" title="{{ $testimonial->image_title }}">
                                </div>
                                <div class="testimonial-person__name">{{ $testimonial->person_name }}</div>
                                <div class="testimonial-person__position">{{ $testimonial->person_position }} - {{ $testimonial->person_location }}</div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    @endforeach

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Btw if you want to make this more generic, consider changing the variable names to something more generic.

### Using Blade include

You can use a blade include function to include the slider on multiple pages, with the following code. Now the problem with this is that you need to map data to the structure defined below:

```php
@include('slider', [
    'testimonials'=>[
        (object) [
            'bg_image'=>'image1.jpg',
            'short_description'=>'test1',
            'person_image'=>'test.jpg',
            'image_alt'=>'test',
            'image_title'=>'test',
            'person_name'=>'Name',
            'person_position'=>'Test',
            'person_location'=>'test'
        ],
        (object) [
            'bg_image'=>'image2.jpg',
            'short_description'=>'test2',
            'person_image'=>'test.jpg',
            'image_alt'=>'test',
            'image_title'=>'test',
            'person_name'=>'Name',
            'person_position'=>'Test',
            'person_location'=>'test'
        ]
    ]
])
```

If you have a lot of mapping logic, you can consider loading it through View Composers. It is generally not recommended to have a lot of logic in your views, even not mapping logic. So in such case it is better to use view composers.

### Using View Composers

Add this to the view which needs to load the slider (I will use `welcome.blade.php` as an example):

```php
{!! $slider ?? '' !!}
```

#### The View composer (MyViewComposer)

Add this to `app/Http/ViewComposers` folder or anywhere you like (change the namespace accordingly). Now the mapping logic is moved to a class, like below:

```php
<?php

namespace App\Http\ViewComposers;

use Illuminate\View\View;

class MyViewComposer
{
    public function compose(View $view)
    {
        $view->with('slider', view('slider', [
            'testimonials'=>[
                (object) [
                    'bg_image'=>'image.jpg',
                    'short_description'=>'test',
                    'person_image'=>'test.jpg',
                    'image_alt'=>'test',
                    'image_title'=>'test',
                    'person_name'=>'Name',
                    'person_position'=>'Test',
                    'person_location'=>'test'
                ],
                (object) [
                    'bg_image'=>'image.jpg',
                    'short_description'=>'test',
                    'person_image'=>'test.jpg',
                    'image_alt'=>'test',
                    'image_title'=>'test',
                    'person_name'=>'Name',
                    'person_position'=>'Test',
                    'person_location'=>'test'
                ]
            ]

        ]));
    }
}
```

The benefit of this is that you can isolate the logic from the view. You can load any dependency you have through the constructor of the view composer and use that for mapping the required data.

##### Adding multiple view composers for different sliders and views

You now can add multiple view composers for different sliders (you still keep only one blade file, which you refer to from the view composer). You can refactor to let's say a template method (or base class) to remove duplicate code in the view composers.

#### Register the view Composer

Create a ServiceProvider (`ViewComposerServiceProvider`) in `app/Providers` folder and register the view composer to the `welcome.blade.php` view. If you have multiple view composers, make sure to bind them to the different views you have here.

```php
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use App\Http\ViewComposers\MyViewComposer;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\View;
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class ViewComposerServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Register bindings in the container.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        // Here you can register all the bindings 
        View::composer(
            'welcome', MyViewComposer::class
        );
    }

    /**
     * Register the service provider.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
        //
    }
}
```

Now add the service provider to your config:

```php
return [
    'providers'=>[
        //..
        \App\Providers\ViewComposerServiceProvider::class
    ]
];
```

The slider will now load on the `welcome.blade.php` view.